# Use OpenSSL to decrypt TLS session from PCAP files

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, tls1.2, pcap

I generated a PCAP file with TLS session, and I have the matching private key used by my HTTPS server.

The TLS session is not using DH for key exchange, so it should be possible to decrypt.

I know OpenSSL can be used to connect to a socket to "actively" handle the TLS session, but is there a way to "passively" decode and decrypt a session?

How can I "feed" the packets (both directions) into the OpenSSL library?

Or maybe another library has such interface? (I know Wireshark/tshark/ssldump can do it, I'm looking for a programmatic way)

Comment: openssl has abstractions that separate the source and destination of "packets" from SSL processing. In principle this should allow you to read encrypted SSL packets from a PCAP file (you need libpcap for this) and write decrypted packets wherever you want, including perhaps another PCAP file. This abstraction is needed to implement non-blocking I/O with SSL, so googling for "openssl with non-blocking I/O" should get you some relevant links. [Here](https://gist.github.com/darrenjs/4645f115d10aa4b5cebf57483ec82eca) is an example that might not need to much modification for your needs.

Comment: I have another library reading the PCAP and performing the TCP reconstruction, so now I have bi-directional stream of TLS packets. I still don't understand how to use the BIO to "feed" both directions into the same SSL context. It looks like also the BIO API is behaving as an active part in the conversion and expects only one direction of packets (either client or server). How do I feed the other side as well?